# AI tree search. Time complexity of 8-queen, by placeing one by one without attack

Tags: artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, n-queens, tree-search

One approach to achieve goal state is to "add a queen to any square in the leftmost empty column such that it is not attacked by any other queen". And this approach will have a state space of 2057 (also wondering How to compute this?)

What is the time complexity if I am using Depth First search algorithm (which I think is the most suitable one)? How about the space complexity?

I am puzzled because the brunching of the search tree is reducing greatly when goes deep. O(8**8) looks too much for time complexity, even for worst case.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus better belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thank you. I am not familiar with the specification. thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Depth First Search](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#depthFirstSearch)'s time depends on how smart the algorithm is to decide which branch to investigate first.

N queens has a cheat: it has a heuristic ([see description on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Solution_construction)) which gives a perfect solution in polynomial time. If your Depth First Search's decisions simply mimic that heuristic's decisions, then your Dept First Search is poly time too.